# On Screen Keyboard not working in Custom Shell, Windows 10 Pro 1709 and 1803

Tags: windows-10, on-screen-keyboard

We are using the On Screen Keyboard in Windows 10 Pro for our Custom Shell application.

Since release 1607 and for 1703 the registry setting "EnableDesktopModeAutoInvoke" in "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7" set to DWORD=1 has provided the On Screen Keyboard for the user running the application, but since relase 1709 this is not working anymore. I have also tried latest 1803 release with the same negative result.

Is there any other solution than the registry setting that can help us out here? 
What have changed in the 1709 (and 1803) release? Is this "by design" or a mistake?

The 1703 support is ending fall 2018.

Thanks.

Comment: Anyone........?

Comment: None..........?